# MySQL how do I merge two columns into one, only showing distinct values?

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following table

**Table: Times**

```
timeid   time
1        10    
2        11   
3        3
```

**Table: Counts**

```
countId timeID numberCounts times
1       1      1            0
2       2      3            11
2       2      3            12
3       2      3            13
4       3      1            0
```

**Query I'm using**

```
SELECT

t.time AS "Start Channel",
c.times AS Lapse

FROM Times t

JOIN Count c ON c.Time_ID=t.Time_ID;
```

**Output**

```
+---------------+----------+
| Start Time    | lapse    |
+---------------+----------+
|          10   |        0 | 
|          11   |       11 | 
|          11   |       12 | 
|          11   |       13 | 
|           3   |        0 | 
+---------------+----------+
```

**Desire Result:**

```
+---------------+
|     TimeS     |
+---------------+
|          10   | 
|          11   | 
|          12   | 
|          13   | 
|           3   | 
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your desired result, it seems like you want:

```
SELECT GREATEST(t.time, c.times) AS `TimeS`
  FROM Times AS t
  JOIN Count AS c
    ON c.Time_ID = t.Time_ID
;
```

but the title of your question makes it sound like you want:

```
SELECT time AS `TimeS`
  FROM Times
UNION
SELECT times
  FROM Count
;
```

(which would also include a `0` in the results, since `Count.times` is sometimes `0`).

Comment: I think your first query is what the OP wants, but probably using `SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to study the DISTINCT keyword, easy and fast solution :)

Comment: I know what distinct keyword does but I don't know how to bring them together with a distinct

Comment: you just put it after the SELECT KEYWORD