# Need to combining two column's data into one column in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am providing one example here to make you all understand what i actually need:
I have a table like this:

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 Child_ID                                               NUMBER(10)
 Father_ID                                              NUMBER(10)
```

Values are:

```
    Child_ID       Father_ID
----------         ----------
         2          1
         4          1
         3          2
         5          3
```

Now I want the hierarchical information for Father id 1. For that I have wrote one query and that is providing me the exact output:

```
**select * from child
start with father_id=1
connect by prior child_id = father_id;**
```

O/P:

```
      Child_ID       Father_ID
----------           ----------
         2            1
         3            2
         5            3
         4            1
```

Now I want the o/p should be like this:

```
ID
-----
1
2
3
4
5
```

I can get it easily by using union key but I don't want to use that.
Is there any other way to get this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the distinct list of child and parent ids from the table, but don't want to use a UNION? Please explain why you don't want to use the simplest and most obvious approach.

Comment: Yes you are correct but I just want to know if there is any other way to get this.

Comment: Two I can think of, one is to SELECT DISTINCT child_id into a temp table, then merge the parent_id into the same table. The second would be to write a union using PL/SQL. Neither would be as fast or efficient as the UNION though. Databases rarely have a many ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks thomas for your information. The temp temp table will not work for me as I have the original table in production, so I can't create any table. So I will use union.

Comment: I have heard about "unpivot" operation in sql. Can I use that to get my desire output?

Comment: You might be able to mung an unpivot query into returning the results you want, I'm not sure I can write one for your example that would be useful for your full system. And I'm pretty sure it won't be any faster or use fewer database resources than the union query would.

Comment: I think the below link will help you solve this problem.

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605541/mysql-how-do-i-merge-two-columns-into-one-only-showing-distinct-values>

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy but you could do :

```
select distinct case when l=1 then child_id else father_id end id
from
    (select child_id, father_id
     from child
     start with father_id=1 connect by prior child_id=father_id) child
     cross join (select level l from dual connect by level < 3)
order by id
;
```